# Could Certbot use a simple URL for HTTP challenge instead of server.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/

Tags: certbot

Could Certbot use a simple URL for HTTP challenge instead of server.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/...

It would be like `server.com/file`

My configuration does not allow subfolders.